# Fallo con el repositorio de GitHub de Commonretrypolicities con jitpack

Tags: maven, jar, java-6

Traté de descargar la versión Commonretrypolicities 3.1.0, pero me lanza un error de que no se ha encontrado el artefacto.
(https://jitpack.io/com/github/muleforge/Common-Retry-Policies/commonretrypolicies-3.1.0/build.log) <--  Aquí dejaré el log.

La forma en como estoy usando en el maven, es igual a como en la pagina de Jitpack, traté también con versiones anteriores a la 3.1.0, pero también sale con error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Fui viendo como solucionar los errores del log, y ahora el unico error que sale es:

> Could not resolve dependencies for project org.mule.modules:commonretrypolicies:jar:3.1.0: Failed to collect dependencies at org.mule:mule-core:jar:3.1.0 -> org.safehaus.jug:jug:jar:asl:2.0.0-osgi[m: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.safehaus.jug:jug:jar:asl:2.0.0-osgi: Could not transfer artifact org.safehaus.jug:jug:pom:2.0.0-osgi from/to codehaus (http://repository.codehaus.org): repository.codehaus.org: Unknown host repository.codehaus.org

¿Cómo solucionar este error o como conseguir el .jar de esta librería?.

Comment: no esta en maven central pero en el repo clojars segun la agina mvn repository: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mule.modules/commonretrypolicies/2.2.1 ahh eso si tiene vulnerabilidades de seguridad, tal vez te comvenga usar jitpack

Comment: Entiendo, revisaré jitpack. Graciaaaaas.

Comment: si te atoras no dudes en editar tu pregunta y ponerle lo que intentes y con gusto te ayudamos con algo mas especifico :)

Comment: la libreria que te da error esta en el depositorui mulesoft: https://mvnrepository.com/repos/mulesoft-public